# Increase column chart performance

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I have a column chart about 2000 columns. It renders very slowly. I get data from Struts and push it directly into chart. I tried to disable animation and use xAxis.labels.step option but it's still slow. How to speed up the chart?

Comment: Disable shadows, animation and don't use categories. If this still won't work faster, use Highstock with dataGrouping.

Comment: If you do not need tooltips disable those and also mouse tracking.

Comment: 1) I would very strongly suggest processing this data first.  
2) I would suggest using an area chart instead of a column chart.
3) You can't possibly see 2,000 columns (or 2,000 points on a line or area chart) on a chart less than half that many pixels wide...  process the data to trim it down to what is useful, and plot it as an area or line